# What is the difference between read and open functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, readfile

Running the following code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    doc = sum(map(int, open('./matrix')))
    print(doc)

    with open("./matrix") as f:

        doc1 = f.read().split('\n')
        print(sum(map(int, doc1)))

        doc2 = sum(map(int, f.read()))
        print(doc2)
```

The output is respectively:

---

```
5537376230390876637302048746832985971773659831892672

5537376230390876637302048746832985971773659831892672

0
```

---

Also, my matrix input file contains:

```
"37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
91942213363574161572522430563301811072406154908250
23067588207539346171171980310421047513778063246676
89261670696623633820136378418383684178734361726757
28112879812849979408065481931592621691275889832738
44274228917432520321923589422876796487670272189318
47451445736001306439091167216856844588711603153276
70386486105843025439939619828917593665686757934951
62176457141856560629502157223196586755079324193331
64906352462741904929101432445813822663347944758178
92575867718337217661963751590579239728245598838407
58203565325359399008402633568948830189458628227828
80181199384826282014278194139940567587151170094390
35398664372827112653829987240784473053190104293586
86515506006295864861532075273371959191420517255829
71693888707715466499115593487603532921714970056938
54370070576826684624621495650076471787294438377604
53282654108756828443191190634694037855217779295145
36123272525000296071075082563815656710885258350721
45876576172410976447339110607218265236877223636045
17423706905851860660448207621209813287860733969412
81142660418086830619328460811191061556940512689692
51934325451728388641918047049293215058642563049483"
```

So can you tell me what the difference between open and read functions?

When I try to add a split on doc2, after that it should be like this:

```
doc2 = sum(map(int, f.read().split("\n")))
```

Yet I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I know that there is question that has been asked, but I try to understand differences between open and read.

I appreciate your answers

Thank you,

Comment: `open` returns a file handle;`read` is a method of a file handle that returns a string (or bytes); `map` applies a function to an iterable

Answer (score 0):

`open()` returns an open file object, from which you may `read` data. Number of bytes at a time, all the data at a time, or iterate over the lines (the behaviour when used with for loop)

In your specific output, the problem lies in using `read` on `f` for `doc2`.

In the earlier line `doc1 = f.read().split('\n')`, all the data has been read and we have reached EOF, so no data remains for `doc2`, hence 0.